# Define $L$-smoothness with respect to $\ell_p$-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

In optimization, a commonly used notion is the $L$-smoothness, which can be defined in the following three ways:

- The gradient is $L$-Lipschitz, e.g. $\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|\le L\|x-y\|$ holds for any $x,y$;
- For any $x,y$, $|f(x)-f(y)-\left<\nabla f(x),y-x\right>|\le \frac L 2 \|x-y\|_2^2$;
- If $f$ is twice differentiable, then the Hessian satisfies $\|\nabla^2 f(x)\|\le L$.

However, it can be seen that in these definitions, the distance measure is all chosen to be the $\ell_2$ norm. Can we generalize the $L$-smoothness into other norms, especially $\ell_p$ norm?

Note that Lipschitzness can be easily defined in terms of $\ell_p$-norm, and the function $f(x)=\|x\|_p$ is 1-Lipschitz with respect to $\ell_p$-norm.

I would like to know if there is some literature of the definition of $L$-smoothness in $\ell_p$ norm, its properties and some example functions. Thank you!